# How to add custom attribute in magento Registration

Tags: magento

I am creating a sign up form for Magneto, I want to add few more information from customer like **place of birth**. How can I do this, I tried many ways but all are use less, please explain step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can go through this link [Magento Module Creater](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.VBfZAvmSxH9)

and create module with Need Add Customer Attribute : yes and it will give the field for your customer attribute. and create field as much as you.after creating field just click Create Magento Module (download) it will give you a ready module with your custom customer attribute. Note:- Selecte **Forms to Use In** in which your field will be populated for user input

Hope this will help you.